# Datatables render body and footer column as numeric

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to format numeric data from a single column on the body and footer section. The formatting is as follows:

- Thousands grouping separator: "."
- Decimal point indicator: ","
- Number of decimal points to show: "0"
- Prefix: "$"

This is my try:

```js
    $('#idtablainforme_ventaporfamilia').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        "searching": false, "paging": false, "ordering": false, "info": false, "autowidth": false,
        columns: [
           { data: "1", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text() },
           { data: "2", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 0, '$') }
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                footer: true,
                title: 'INFORME DE VENTAS POR FAMILIA',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'Exporta a EXCEL',
            }
        ]
    });
```

This is the data:

```
CHEQUERA MUJER 5231760 
CARTERA 3487630 
BILLETERA MUJER 2155120 
NECESER 21980 
COSMETIQUERA 10990 
SET DE VIAJE 10990
TOTAL 12925150
```

But it renders the following table:

```html
<table id="idtablainforme_ventaporfamilia" class="table table-striped table-striped table-bordered nowrap dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th>
                FAMILIA
            </th>
            <th>
                VENTA
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>
                TOTAL
            </th>
            <th style="text-align: right">
                12.925.150
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>CHEQUERA MUJER</td>
            <td>$5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CARTERA</td>
            <td>$5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BILLETERA MUJER</td>
            <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NECESER</td>
            <td>$21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>COSMETIQUERA</td>
            <td>$10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SET DE VIAJE</td>
            <td>$10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that the formatting on the body section is wrong ($5 instead of $5.231.760) and it doesn't format the footer section.

Comment: Where should it format the footer section ..? There is no code for that. But I really cant replicate the wrong rendering, have tried all versions .9-.16, here is a .11 example -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1005/

Comment: @davidkonrad The "TOTAL" value should go in the footer section, and I don't know how to fomat it

Answer (score 2):

Look at the source around line [**14489**](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L14889) (the exact line number will probably change in the future). The renderers is in fact an object literal on the form :

```js
render = {
  number: function(..) {
    return {
      display: function(..) {
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

So you can call the renderer programmatically with

```js
$.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 0, '$').display(value)
```

Now you can use `footerCallback` to render its value using `render.number().display()`

```js
footerCallback: function(tfoot, data, start, end, display) {
  var $th = $(tfoot).find('th').eq(1);
  $th.text( $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 0, '$').display( $th.text() )) 
},
```

Notice that the value *must* be an unformatted number, i.e `12925150` not `12.925.150` - otherwise it will fail

**http://jsfiddle.net/wotyo6nL/**

Comment: If I wanted to put the footer in bold, or increase the size of the footer letter, how would it be without leaving thousands formatting?

Comment: @Danilo, in this case you can just use CSS `table.dataTable tfoot th:nth-child(2) {` -> http://jsfiddle.net/wotyo6nL/1/

Comment: yes, but when exporting? Will he do it with styles?

Comment: @Danilo, no styling is exported per default anyway; logically not with CSV / Excel, with PDF you have to customise the export yourself but it is possible. I dont know with printing, never tried.